# How do you select every nth item in an array?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking to find a way in Ruby to select every nth item in an array. For instance, selecting every second item would transform:

```
["cat", "dog", "mouse", "tiger"]
```

into:

```
["dog", "tiger"]
```

Is there a Ruby method to do so, or is there any other way to do it?

I tried using something like:

```
[1,2,3,4].select {|x| x % 2 == 0}
# results in [2,4]
```

but that only works for an array with integers, not strings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could also use step:

```
n = 2
a = ["cat", "dog", "mouse", "tiger"]
b = (n - 1).step(a.size - 1, n).map { |i| a[i] }
```

Comment: This is perfect. So clean. Thank you so much mu :)

Comment: Thanks, please note that I fixed an off-by-one issue that `n=3` would show.

Comment: The `step` didn't make sense to me initially as I've not used that form before. It's equivalent to `(n-1 ... a.size).step(n).map{|i| a[i] }`

Answer (score 60):

You can use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001514):

```
["cat", "dog", "mouse", "tiger"].each_slice(2).map(&:last)
# => ["dog", "tiger"]
```

Update:

As mentioned in the comment, `last` is not always suitable, so it could be replaced by `first`, and skipping first element:

```
["cat", "dog", "mouse", "tiger"].drop(1).each_slice(2).map(&:first)
```

Unfortunately, making it less elegant.

IMO, the most elegant is to use `.select.with_index`, which Nakilon suggested in his comment:

```
["cat", "dog", "mouse", "tiger"].select.with_index{|_,i| (i+1) % 2 == 0}
```

Comment: Oh crap. If the array has odd number of elements, this will return last one as well. Never mind, let it stay here as an idea...

Comment: Thanks so much for the pointer Mladen and the resource for "each_slice" :)

Answer (score 5):

How about this -

```
arr = ["cat", "dog", "mouse", "tiger"]
n = 2
(0... arr.length).select{ |x| x%n == n-1 }.map { |y| arr[y] } 
    #=> ["dog", "tiger"]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need that in other places, you could add a method to `Enumerable`:

```
module Enumerable
   def select_with_index
      index = -1
      (block_given? && self.class == Range || self.class == Array)  ?  select { |x| index += 1; yield(x, index) }  :  self
   end
end

p ["cat", "dog", "mouse", "tiger"].select_with_index { |x, i| x if i % 2 != 0 }
```

Note: This is not my original code. I got it from [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3746) when I had had the same need as you.

Comment: In 1.9 you can write this as `to_enum.with_index.select`

Comment: In 1.9 you can write this as `.select.with_index`

Answer (score 4):

Yet another ways:

```
xs.each_with_index.map { |x, idx| x if idx % 2 != 0 }.compact

xs.each_with_index.select { |x, idx| idx % 2 }.map(&:first)

xs.values_at(*(1...xs.length).step(2))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `values_at` method. You can find it easily in [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method).

Here are some examples:

```
array = ["Hello", 2, "apple", 3]
array.values_at(0,1) # pass any number of arguments you like
=> ["Hello", 2]

array.values_at(0..3) # an argument can be a range
=>["Hello", 2, "apple", 3]
```

I believe this would fix your problem with "dog" and "tiger"

```
array = ["cat", "dog", "mouse", "tiger"]
array.values_at(1,3)
```

and with your another array

```
[1,2,3,4].values_at(1,3)
=> [2, 4]
```

Comment: You can make the index args dynamic with array.values_at *(0..array.length).step(2).

Comment: @pduey should be `array.values_at *(0...array.length).step(2)` (three dots); otherwise there may be an extra `nil` at the end of the results. Also, this unpacks arguments for the call, which seems not great for a large number of elements (temporarily all those index values are in memory along with the original array).

Answer (score 4):

If what you are looking for, is to select only odd or even numbers, there's a very simple way:

```
animals.select.with_index{ |_, i| i.odd? }
```

e.g.

```
['a','b','c','d'].select.with_index{ |_,i| i.odd? }
# => ["b", "d"]
```

Comment: This doesn't work - it returns an array booleans, false, true, false, true.

Comment: @MarcO'Morain Not for me it doesn't. Try copying the example code and running it.

Comment: Aha, the OP edited their answer after I pointed out the error.

Answer (score 3):

I like both Anshul's and Mu's answers and want to refine and simplify them a bit by submitting each as a monkeypatch to Enumerable:

**Mu's**

```
module Enumerable
  def every_nth(n)
    (n - 1).step(self.size - 1, n).map { |i| self[i] }
  end
end
```

**Anshul's**

```
module Enumerable
  def every_nth(n)
    (0... self.length).select{ |x| x%n == n-1 }.map { |y| self[y] }
  end
end
```

Then it is very easy to work with.  For example, consider:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]

a.every_nth(2)
 => [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24] 

a.every_nth(3)
 => [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24]

a.every_nth(5)
 => [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
my_array = ["cat", "dog", "mouse", "tiger"]

my_new_array = my_array.select {|x| index(x) % 2 == 0}
```

Comment: It needs to be `my_array.index(x)` instead of just `index(x)`, and it will still not work robustly - because `index` is looking for the first occurrence of that value, this will e.g. miss `dog` in `["cat", "dog", "dog", "tiger"]` (the first `"dog"` is in the wrong place, therefore the second one is also rejected).

Answer (score -1):

```
class Array
  def every(n)
    select {|x| index(x) % n == 0}
  end
end
```