# Firing an event each tree iterations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, performance, iteration

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to know what is a common practice\technique to iterate an array composed from a lot of data and fire an event each *three* iterations.

I can do something like this

```
# "fire_the_event" is a method
count = 0
array.each do |element|
  count += 1

  fire_the_event if count % 3 == 0
end
```

but there is a "better"\"more performant" way to `fire_the_event` each *three* times?

Comment: This has little to do with your question, but please note that `count += 1` has the same effect as `count = count + 1` and is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001514) method

```
array.each_slice(3) do |elements|
  fire_the_event
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Your example code is incomplete, as it doesn't illustrate what you really need.

Essentially, your code does the following:

```
(array.length / 3).times{fire_the_event}
```

But I doubt that's what you really need.

Anyway, take a look at this SO question: [How do you select every nth item in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689186/ruby-how-do-you-select-every-nth-item-in-an-array)

If you do need to traverse each element, use `with_index`:

```
array.each_with_index do |element, index|
  # perform something with each element

  # but fire the event only with every third:
  fire_the_event if index % 3 == 0
end
```