# Looping through an array with step

Tags: ruby, loops, iteration

I want to look at every n-th elements in an array. In C++, I'd do this:

```
for(int x = 0; x<cx; x+=n){
    value_i_care_about = array[x];
    //do something with the value I care about.  
}
```

I want to do the same in Ruby, but can't find a way to "step". A `while` loop could do the job, but I find it distasteful using it for a known size, and expect there to be a better (more Ruby) way of doing this.

Comment: Nothing about the step could be found :)  each.. or for loop is easy to find.. I want to do every 5th or 10th or 9th element in the array

Comment: Benjamin's answer is incorrect. You should look at Levi's or David's answer.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense that `1.step(3, 2)` gives 1 and 3. In this code the step is 2, so the second element gets skipped. Which leaves you with 1 and 3.

Comment: By the way, this has nothing to do with Rails, it's a Ruby question.

Comment: [How do you select every nth item in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689186)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Ranges have a `step` method which you can use to skip through the indexes:

```
(0..array.length - 1).step(2).each do |index|
  value_you_care_about = array[index]
end
```

Or if you are comfortable using `...` with ranges the following is a bit more concise:

```
(0...array.length).step(2).each do |index|
  value_you_care_about = array[index]
end
```

Comment: You can use `(0...array.length)` instead of `(0..array.length - 1)`

Answer (score 25):

```
array.each_slice(n) do |e, *_|
  value_i_care_about = e
end
```

Answer (score 9):

Just use step() method from Range class which returns an enumerator

```
(1..10).step(2) {|x| puts x}
```

Comment: @baash05 you do realize a range is a native type (read: class) so you're not taking up a million integers worth of memory, right?

Answer (score 3):

We can iterate while skipping over a range of numbers on every iteration e.g.:

```
1.step(10, 2) { |i| print "#{i} "}
```

http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/a-wealth-of-ruby-loops-and-iterators/

So something like:

```
array.step(n) do |element|
  # process element
end
```

Comment: You missed the bit about the step. That was the important bit.

Comment: Just feeling a bit under the weather tonight =D

Comment: This doesn't work. `Array` doesn't have a `step` method, so you will get "Undefined method for step". `1.step(10,2)` does work, but that doesn't iterate over an array. Levi has the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah.. but in Ben's defence.. it was enough to figure it out.  And Levi's doesn't iterate over the array either.  Both excellent answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great example for the use of the modulo operator `%`

When you grasp this concept, you can apply it in a great number of different programming languages, without having to know them in and out.

```
step = 2
["1st","2nd","3rd","4th","5th","6th"].each_with_index do |element, index|
  puts element if index % step == 1
end

#=> "2nd"
#=> "4th"
#=> "6th"
```

Comment: had to vote you down... if n is 1000 then and I've got 10000 elements I've just done 10000 if's I didn't need to to get 10 elements.

Comment: I was just wondering why it got downvoted.. thanks for letting me know

Comment: Of course you're absolutely right with that. The negative impact gets larger, the bigger your step size is. If you're as curious about it as I was just now, see the significant benchmark results in this gist: https://gist.github.com/3936015

Comment: excellent search dave.  Anytime a compare is in the loop it's run each time.. if you can get if's out of your loop it runs faster.  I like to watch my cycles and let the .... take care of them selves.

Comment: then, I'll just replace my `if`s with `unless`... jk ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
def step(interval, &block)
    ((interval -1)...self.length).step(interval) do |value|
        block.call(self[value])
    end
end
end
```

You could add the method to the class Array

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].select.each_with_index { |_,i| i % 2 == 0 }
=> [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Chaining of iterators is very useful.

Comment: Um, maybe, but in this case completely unnecessary. Just use the block form of select:  `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].select(&:odd?)`