# "Interpolate" an array (add new elements between existing)

Tags: ruby

I can't seem to find a ruby-way to transform this

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

into

```
[0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]
```

e.g, insert new elements based on existing ones applying some rule.

EDIT: I'm asking about a general case, not necessarily a 0.5 increment. Say, when elements are not successive:

```
[1, 3, 12] => [1, 2, 3, 7.5, 12]
```

So the accepted answer is just perfect here, thanks.

Comment: There can't be built-in method for every possible need. Sometimes you just have to roll up your sleeves and implement. Can you do it in non-ruby way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looping through an array with step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021812/looping-through-an-array-with-step)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3]

def rule(x, y)
  (x + y) / 2.0
end

arr.each_cons(2).flat_map{|x, y| [x, rule(x, y), y]} # => [0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 2, 2, 2.5, 3]
```

Comment: `arr.each_cons(2).flat_map{ |x, y| [x, rule(x, y), y]}`