# Looping through an array with changed step based on last loop's result

Tags: ruby, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have learned about this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021812/looping-through-an-array-with-step), and know we can do this:

```
(0..array.length - 1).step(2).each do |index|
    value_you_care_about = array[index]
end
```

However I found that syntax cannot go for a step which changed self by result of last loop. Like C++ code as follow:

```
for(int x = 1; x<cx; x+=x){
    value_i_care_about = array[x];
    //do something with the value I care about.  
}
```

This is not same to that question, since `x` plus itself as a loop step. Does anyone know how to code this? This is useful such as in a `merge-sort` implementation.

Very appricate for any help!

---

Update:

As far as I know is we only can implement by following code:

```
step = 1
while step < nums.length do
    // do sth.
    step += step
end
```

Is there a better implementation?

Comment: "Is there a better implementation?" - What's wrong with that one? That's exactly how I'd've written it.

Comment: @Amadan just want to know is there a syntax can implement like "(0..array.length - 1).step(2).each"

Answer (score 1):

If you hate phpish declarations in front of the loop (`step = 1`), as I do, you might find the approach with infinite `loop` useful:

```
loop.inject(1) do |x| 
  break if x > 10
  puts x
  x += x
end
#⇒ 1
#  2
#  4
#  8
```

Comment: The assignment in the last expression `x += x` isn't neccessary. `x + x` would also do it.

Comment: Indeed, I wrote `x += x` just for the sake of conformance to the original code by OP.