# Reduce array to set number of items?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a Ruby array of 300 items. I want to reduce that array down to a set number of items, evenly picked from the array.

The number of items in the array will not be the same every time, nor will the number of items needed.

Something like this:

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
num_of_items = 4
final_arr = [0, 5, 10, 15]
```

Comment: Your example shows four items returned after requesting five. Was that your intent?

Comment: You need to explain what should be the reduction algorithm? How many items must be in the array? How do you choose them? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Seems similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4689413/624590  (assuming you want to be able to get every nth item).

Comment: This is poorly asked. Your code does nothing, so it looks like you're fishing for code to solve your problem, instead of showing us what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
#=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
num_of_items = 4
#=> 4
arr.each_slice(arr.size/num_of_items + 1).map(&:first)
#=> [0, 5, 10, 15] 

arr = (0..16).to_a
#=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

num_of_items = 5
#=> 5
arr.each_slice(arr.size/num_of_items + 1).map(&:first)
#=> [0, 4, 8, 12, 16]
```

OR

[Numeric#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step)

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
#=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
num_of_items = 4
#=> 4
arr.first.step(arr.size, arr.size/num_of_items + 1).map { |i| arr[i] }
#=> [0, 5, 10, 15]
arr = (0..16).to_a
#=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

num_of_items = 5
#=> 5
arr.first.step(arr.size, arr.size/num_of_items + 1).map { |i| arr[i] }
#=> [0, 4, 8, 12, 16]
```

Comment: This is spot on for what I was needing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're picking a given number of items at random from this array, use [`sample`](http://www.omniref.com/ruby/classes/Array##sample) -

```
$ arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
$ arr.sample(5)
 => [1, 3, 5, 4, 12]
$ arr.sample(5)
 => [15, 6, 13, 5, 11]
```

Comment: Not looking for random. Needs to be evenly spaced.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal of your algorithm is exactly as shown above, you could use `in_groups_of`, then grab the first element of each child array:

```
1.9.3p484 :014 > num_of_items = 5
 => 5 

1.9.3p484 :011 > arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
 => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] 

1.9.3p484 :012 > arr.in_groups_of(num_of_items)
 => [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, nil, nil, nil, nil]] 

1.9.3p484 :013 > arr.in_groups_of(num_of_items).map(&:first)
 => [0, 5, 10, 15]
```

Comment: `num_of_items = 5` yet the result has 4 items.

Comment: `in_groups_of` is an `Active Support Array` method not ruby, the question is not a rails question but a ruby one