# Get nth element of an array in Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, arrays

I have a simple array and I am trying to grab every 2nd item in the array. Unfortunately I am more familiar with JavaScript than Ruby...

In JavaScript I could simply do

```js
var arr = [1, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 9],
    otherArr = [];

for (i=0; i < arr.length; i=i+2) {
    // Do something... for example:
    otherArr.push( arr[i] );
}
```

Now how can I do this in Ruby?

Comment: In Ruby you can index arrays just like in other languages. Starting with index zero. What's the problem here? Why not Google "ruby array" and read the documentation on the Array class?

Comment: This question requires very little research effort, apparently you gave none. Please review [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: To get the nth element of an array on ruby you should do `arr[n-1]`. But this is not what you want, so once the lock for edit is available, please someone change it.

Comment: Please check my answer below..you can use step

Comment: Some more options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689186/how-do-you-select-every-nth-item-in-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = 2
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
b = (n - 1).step(a.size - 1, n).map{ |i| a[i] }

output => ["b", "d"]
```

Try above code

Comment: Won't `b = n.step(a.size, n).map{ |i| a[i-1] }` be more succinct?

Comment: Or  `(1..a.size).step(n).map{ |i| a[i] }`.

Answer (score 3):

For

```
arr = [1, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 9]
new_array = []
```

To get the odds,

```
arr.each_with_index{|x, i| new_array << x if i.odd?} 
new_array #=> ['foo', 'baz']
```

And the evens,

```
arr.each_with_index{|x, i| new_array.push(x) if i.even?} #more javascript-y with #push
new_array #=> [1, 'bar', 9]
```

Comment: It does not work - it simply runs `.odd?` on each element is `'baz'.odd?` true?

Comment: It is calling `odd?` on the index of the element inside the array.

Comment: I have - `NoMethodError: undefined method `even?' for "foo":String`

Comment: I tried this one, but it can't find the method even? `NoMethodError: undefined method `even?' for "foo":String`

Comment: Thanks for the catch, @UriAgassi I was just running it with integers. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

A nice way is to take each pair, and select only the first in the pair:

```
arr = [1, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 9]
other_arr = arr.each_slice(2).map(&:first)
# => [1, "bar", 9]
```

Comment: you don't need a block: `arr.each_slice(2).map(&:first)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-select) together with [`Enumerator#with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index):

```
arr.select.with_index { |e, i| i.even? }
#=> [1, "bar", 9]
```

Maybe it's easier to read with 1-based indices:

```
arr.select.with_index(1) { |e, i| i.odd? }
#=> [1, "bar", 9]
```

Or to find every nth element, as [Cary Swoveland points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313332/get-nth-element-of-an-array-in-ruby/23314212#comment35695659_23314212):

```
n = 2
arr.select.with_index(1) { |e, i| (i % n).zero? }
#=> [1, "bar", 9]
```

Comment: Or `arr.select.with_index(1) { |e,i| (i%n).zero? }` for every nth item. I prefer your solution because it is the simplest and reads the best.

Answer (score 1):

same thing you can do it in ruby also:

```
arr = [1, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 9],
otherArr = [];

arr.each_with_index do |value,index|
  # Do something... for example:
  otherArr <<  arr[i] if i.even?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to combine `each_with_index` with `map`.

```
arr = [1, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 9]
arr.each_with_index.map { |i,k| i if k.odd? }.compact
#=> ["foo", "baz"]
```

However you can also use the [values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-values_at) method

for odd indexes

```
arr.values_at(*(1..arr.size).step(2)).compact
#=> ["foo", "baz"]
```

and for even indexes

```
arr.values_at(*(0..arr.size).step(2))
#=> [1, "bar", 9]
```

(I don't consider it wise to do that :-) )

Comment: You don't need `to_a` and you can omit `compact` (as it won't work with `nil` elements) by excluding the last element: `arr.values_at(*(0...arr.size).step(2))`

Answer (score 1):

`each_slice` can be used nicely for this situation:

```
arr = [1, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 9]
n = 2
arr.each_slice(n) { |a1, a2| p a1 }

> 1, "bar", 9

arr.each_slice(n) { |a1, a2| p a2 }

> "foo", "baz"
```